Pivot wider to replace duplicate null columns when combining files with different columns in Power Query for Power BI
I'm combining multiple data files in Power Query for Power BI. Each of my files has over a hundred columns, some of which are named the same and most of which are different. Here is a truncated example.
File A



ID
Desc
Alt
StdDev
Item1
Item2




1
Foo
f
.2
12344
144


2
Bar
b1
.3
12355
155


3
Baz
b2
.255
12366
166



File B



ID
Desc
StdDev
IDplus
Item10
Item11




1
Foo
.5
thing1
944
9944


2
Bar
.8
thing2
955
9955


3
Baz
.111
thing3
966
9966



What I have now after combining:



ID
Desc
Alt
StdDev
Item1
Item2
IDplus
Item10
Item11




1
Foo
f
.2
12344
144
null
null
null


2
Bar
b1
.3
12355
155
null
null
null


3
Baz
b2
.255
12366
166
null
null
null


1
Foo
null
.5
null
null
thing1
944
9944


2
Bar
null
.8
null
null
thing2
955
9955


3
Baz
null
.111
null
null
thing3
966
9966



The result I'm hoping for:



ID
Desc
Alt
Item1
Item2
IDplus
Item10
Item11
StdDevA
StdDevB




1
Foo
f
12344
144
thing1
944
9944
.2
.5


2
Bar
b1
12355
155
thing2
955
9955
.3
.8


3
Baz
b2
12366
166
thing3
966
9966
.255
.111



So what I'm essentially trying to do is collapse (non-technical use of that word) these into fewer rows. Since all the columns are there anyway, it seems like a waste of space to duplicate a lot of data, since I have a few hundred columns and many thousands of rows.
I know my current result and the one I hope for are semantically the same, but it feels like the desired result will be less memory intensive.
Questions:

Is it correct that the desired will be more efficient for storage and working memory?
How would I make the transforms to make these changes?

Thanks in advance!
I've used Power Query in Power BI. I did a folder import and multiple transforms including custom column code.

Assuming that ID is identical throughout all your files, and that columns with identical names in different files have the same content, you can get your desired output by just doing sequential nested joins, only expanding the distinct columns each time.

No need to pivot if what you post represents the file contents. It is just a matter of doing sequential joins.
Here is sample code which assumes that your files are tab-separated text files.
You may need to use some of the Options for the Table.PromoteHeaders function depending on your real data.
If the files are something else, you will need to change the file processing routines that are being used, but this should get you started:
let
//Get the folder files
    Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\myCSVfiles"),

//filter to select only the relevant files
//  change this to something that works
    #"Binaries" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".txt"))[Content],

//Assuming there is a column of binaries, and that these represent tab-separated text files,you can use the following
//If the tables are something else, you will need to replace the 
//   `Table.PromoteHeaders(Csv.Document(Text.FromBinary(#"Binaries"{0}),null,"#(tab)")),` lines with something appropriate

    #"Combine Binaries" = List.Accumulate(
        List.Skip(#"Binaries"),
        Table.PromoteHeaders(Csv.Document(Text.FromBinary(#"Binaries"{0}),null,"#(tab)")),
        (s,c)=> let 
            nextTable = Csv.Document(Text.FromBinary(c),null,"#(tab)"),
            #"Promote Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(nextTable),
            Join = Table.NestedJoin(s,"ID",#"Promote Headers","ID","Joined",JoinKind.FullOuter),
            #"s Columns" = Table.ColumnNames(s),
            #"Next Table Columns" = Table.ColumnNames(Join[Joined]{0}),
            #"Expand Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Join,"Joined", List.RemoveMatchingItems(#"Next Table Columns",#"s Columns"))
        in #"Expand Table")
in 
    #"Combine Binaries"


Thanks, I got pulled away on another project—I'll get back to it soon. Is this Power Query mechanism the only way to do what I'm asking, or can it be done through their "wizard"? I also discovered that using PowerBI's wizard will drop columns without warning if there are duplicate header names in a file.

The nested joins cannot be done through the wizard.  Perhaps someone else can figure out how to get a similar result using only the wizard, but it likely would not be as flexible. Not something I would tackle. And yes, Tables in general cannot have two columns with the same name, no matter in PQ or PBI.
